# How do i put the table number and caption on same line in latex with documentclass{cas-dc}

Tags: tables, formatting, captions, overleaf

I have a table with code and a table like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, fleqn, numbers]{cas-dc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{table*}[t]
\begin{center}
     \caption{Caption of table.}
    \label{tab:table-a}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
    \small
\begin{tabular}{lccll}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Methods} & Type & Target & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Model} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} ABC \\DEE\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
 L-AA \cite{Christian2013Intriguing}&   123&    456&    5678&   Expensive  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: the table number and caption on two line in latex]

I added the cas-common.sty file and added this comment `\cs_new:Npn \__make_tbl_caption:nn #1#2 { %\l_tbl_align_tl <-- THIS LINE \skip_vertical:N \l_tbl_abovecap_skip  {\parbox{ \dimexpr(\l_tbl_width_dim)} {\rightskip=0pt\sffamily\small\textbf{\color{scolor}#1}\par#2\par\vskip4pt }} \skip_vertical:N \l_tbl_belowcap_skip }`in my Overleaf project. But It don't have any change.

**Question:** How do I put the table number and caption on same line in LaTeX?

Comment: If this is for publicaton, don't mess with their caption style.  Also, use '`\centering` instead of `center`.